# Acess UserControl inside another UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have defined a UserControl for DateTime picking in Windows 8 store apps. The control consists of 3 checkboxes and hast a property to channel out the selected date time.
When I include this control into another UserControl and name it, I am not able to access it from C# code.

```
 //...Page content....
 <TextBlock Text="Erledigen bis:" FontSize="16"/>
 <local:DateTimePicker Name="dtp_dueUntil"  />
 <TextBlock Text="Wichtigkeit" FontSize="16"/>
 //...Page content....
```

*dtp_dueUntil* is not known in my code behind file.
Am I doing something awefull wrong, or just missing a point here?

Comment: I was able to find a workaroung by finding the object when I need it via var picker = this.FindName("dtp_dueUntil");

Answer (score 0):

You should not access controls like that, unless you have no other choice. In your case, iF you what to expose selected `DateTime` in your first user control, then simply declare a `Dependency Property` which will hold and update this value (via DataBinding or event).